# Получить GET - параметр с квадратными скобками

Tags: javascript, php, html, get, форма

Вставляю значения GET-параметров с url в форму с помощью скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixedEncodeURI (str) {
    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
}

function getQueryParam(param) {
    var result =  window.location.search.match(
        new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
    );

    return result ? result[3] : false;
}

window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value =  getQueryParam("ticket");
        document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value =  getQueryParam("qualcomm");
};
</script>
```

Дело в том, что параметр **ticket** имеет синтаксис типа **[000033]** и квадратные скобки в url из-за кодирования принимают вид **%5B** и **%5D** соответственно, т.е. url будет типа *http://site.com/rating?ticket=%5B000033%5D&qualcomm=Testing*.

Поэтому в поле формы вставляется **%5B000033%5D**, как сделать так, чтобы вставлялись скобки вместо их кодировки, т.е. **[000033]**

Comment: Попробуйте urlencode и urldecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По рабоче-крестьянски используйте функцию `decodeURI()`

```js
function getQueryParam(param) {
  // const search = window.location.search;
  const search = "?ticket=%5B000033%5D&qualcomm=Testing";
  var result = search.match(
    new RegExp("(\\?|&)" + param + "(\\[\\])?=([^&]*)")
  );
  return result ? decodeURI(result[3]) : "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value = getQueryParam("ticket");
  document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value = getQueryParam("qualcomm");
};
```

```html
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id" /><br/>
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm" />
```

Для современных браузеров используйте функцию `URLSearchParams`

```js
function getQueryParam(param) {
  // const search = window.location.search;
  const search = "?ticket=%5B000033%5D&qualcomm=Testing";
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.substring(1));
  return params.get(param);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id").value = getQueryParam("ticket");
  document.getElementById("pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm").value = getQueryParam("qualcomm");
};
```

```html
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id" /><br/>
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm" />
```

Или с полной автоматизацией

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // const search = window.location.search;
  const search = "?ticket=%5B000033%5D&qualcomm=Testing";
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search.substring(1));
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.params');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    const input = inputs.item(i);
    const param = input.getAttribute("data-get");
    input.value = params.get(param);
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ticket_id" class="params" data-get="ticket" /><br/>
<input id="pwebcontact228_field-ratecomm" class="params" data-get="qualcomm" />
```

А еще все это можно делать на сервере

Comment: @АлиЖакупов тогда отметьте ответ как верный